# DTO Assembler, como utiliza-lo realmente?

Tags: java, ddd, automapper

Eu estou lendo sobre DTO e tbm viewmodel no ASP.NET e queria fazer algo parecido com isso no JAVA. 
Se não me engano o DTO é uma forma de trafegar dados entre as camadas de uma forma específica sem ter q alterar as entidades de domínio.

Pois bem, no ASP temos o automapper que vai transformar uma Entidade em um ViewModel/DTO e para java eu encontrei algumas soluções que facilitam.

Minha dificuldade é o processo reverso, transformar um ViewModel/DTO em entidade.
Imaginem o seguinte cenário:

Tenho uma entidade:

```
public class Pedido{
   private long codigo;
   private Cliente cliente;
   private Vendedor vendedor;
}
```

e um DTO

```
public class PedidoDTO{
   private long codigo;
   private long codCliente;
   private long nomeCliente;
   private long codVendedor;
   private long nomeVendedor;
}
```

Transformar a entidade em DTO é fácil, pq o DTO é bem mais simples, dá até pra criar umas lib pra fazer isso, mas o processo contrário já é mais complexo. Eu mesmo criei um mapper aqui pra fazer isso "na mão".

```
    public Pedido preencherModelo(PedidoDTO pDTO, Pedido pPedido) {     
            pPedido.setCodigo(pDTO.getCodigo());
            if (pDTO.getCodCliente() > 0){
                Cliente lCliente = _servicoCliente.buscar(pDTO.getCodCliente()); 
                pPedido.setCliente(lCliente);
            }       
            if (pDTO.getCodVendedor() > 0){
                Vendedor lVendedor = _servicoVendedor.buscar(pDTO.getCodVendedor()); 
                pPedido.setVendedor(lVendedor);
            }
            return pPedido;
}
```

A questão é: To fazendo besteira ? vcs tem uma solução melhor que essa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converter `Entity` para DTO através do *pattern assembler* é errado, quebra o sentido do DTO que é um pattern para transferência de objetos. Veja que ele pode ser composto de várias entidades. O correto é usar métodos `set` das instâncias dos objetos nas classes de serviços, pegando os valores desses DTO's e montar as entidades, já ao contrário, como você mesmo falou é simples, pois você estaria trabalhando de forma correta com o pattern.

Mas tem uma forma que mesmo sendo errado funcionaria, mas só iria ser válido se a associação fosse *1x1* entre entity x DTO, utilizando function.

Ex: para converter utilizando transformes para objetos e listas com Guava:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.common.base.Function;

    /**
     * Classe de transformação para popular os dados em DTOs, seguindo o pattern
     * Transfer Object Assembler.
     */
    public class Transformer {

        /**
         * Executa a transformação de um objeto para um DTO.
         * 
         * @param from
         * @param function
         * @return <F, T> T
         */
        public static <F, T> T transform(F from, Function<? super F, ? extends T> function) {
            return (from == null) ? null : function.apply(from);
        }

        /**
         * Executa a transformação de uma lista de objetos para uma lista de DTOs.
         * 
         * @param fromList
         * @param function
         * @return <F, T> List<T>
         */
        public static <F, T> List<T> transform(List<F> source, Function<? super F, ? extends T> function) {
            List<T> out = new ArrayList<>(source.size());

            for (F from : source) {
                out.add(function.apply(from));
            }    
            return out;
        }    
    }
```

Pattern assembler:

```
import java.util.List;
import br.com.myapp.model.dto.AuthUserDTO;
import br.com.myapp.model.entity.AuthUser;
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

/**
 * Classe que transforma entidade USUARIOS em DTO.
 * 
 * @author Dilnei Cunha
 */
public class AuthUserDTOAssembler implements Function<AuthUser, AuthUserDTO>{

    /**
     * Método responsável por fazer a conversão da entidade USUARIOS em um AuthUserDTO.
     */
@Override
public AuthUserDTO apply(AuthUser e) {

    AuthGroupDTO groupDTO = Transformer.transform(e.getAuthGroup(), new  AuthGroupDTOAssembler());

    return new AuthUserDTO(e.getId(),
                       e.getName(),
                       e.getPassword(),
                       e.getEmail(),
                       e.getCreationDate(),
                       e.getLastModificationdate(),
                       e.getLastAccessDate(),
                       e.getAtivo(),
                       e.getUserName(),
                       e.getRamal(),
                       groupDTO);
    }
}
```

Como ficaria o serviço que utilizaria esses patterns...

```
/**
 * Método responsável por buscar um AuthUserDTO pelo ID do usuário.
 */
@Override
public AuthUserDTO findById(Long id) {
    return Transformer.transform(authUserRepository.findUserById(id), new AuthUserDTOAssembler());
}
```

Agora vamos fazer o processo inverso, de transformar um ou uma lista de DTO's em objetos, mas tendo em mente que a associação fosse 1x1. Para isto, basta inverter os objetos na implementação da function, ex:

```
import java.util.List;
import br.com.myapp.model.dto.AuthUserDTO;
import br.com.myapp.model.entity.AuthUser;
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

/**
 * @author Dilnei Cunha
 */
public class AuthUserAssembler implements Function<AuthUserDTO, AuthUser>{

@Override
public AuthUser apply(AuthUserDTO e) {

    AuthGroup group = Transformer.transform(e.getAuthGroupDTO(), new  AuthGroupAssembler());

    return new AuthUser(e.getId(),
                       e.getName(),
                       e.getPassword(),
                       e.getEmail(),
                       e.getCreationDate(),
                       e.getLastModificationdate(),
                       e.getLastAccessDate(),
                       e.getAtivo(),
                       e.getUserName(),
                       e.getRamal(),
                       group);
    }
}
```